# What is the difference between getWinSize getWinSizeInPixels in cc.Director?

Tags: cocos2d-x, cocos2d-x-3.0, cocos2d-js

What is the intended difference between these 2 functions:

```
    var size = cc.Director.getInstance().getWinSize();
    var sizePx = cc.Director.getInstance().getWinSizeInPixels();
```

In my case they both return the exact same value.

In which cases should they return different values?

Comment: on retina devices on ios pixels is 2x the point size

Answer (score 2):

In recent versions of Cocos2dx the given answer is no longer accurate, specifically since the framework has dropped support of the explicit retina mode in favor of providing the programmer with ability to set the resolution of the game independently of the screen and asset resolution, performing scaling when necessary.

Strictly speaking, function `getWinSize()` returns the value of whatever resolution you choose (using `CCGLView::setDesignResolution(float, float, ResolutionPolicy)`), in pixels; `getWinSizeInPixels()` returns design resolution, multiplied by the content scale factor, which is, again, provided by you with `CCDirector::setContentScaleFactor(float)`. If you do not provide the values with these functions, Cocos2dx will choose the design resolution based on an arbitrary value depending of the current platform. For example, on iOS it will use the size of the provided CAEAGLView in pixels (which may be less than the real device resolution in some cases), both `getWinSize()` and `getWinSizeInPixels()` will return the same value.

`getWinSize()` and `getWinSizeInPixels()` will return different values if you are scaling your resources to the game resolution. In such case `getWinSizeInPixels()` indicates what the resolution would be if you didn't have to scale the resources.

Some possible setups to illustrate how the system works:

- 1 set of images, 1 design resolution, many device resolutions = images scaled whenever design != device (lower quality of looks for upscale, unnecessary memory/cpu usage for downscale), single resolution layout code (presumably simpler)
- multiple sets of images, 1 design resolution, many device resolutions = less need to scale the images because different assets cover wider scope of targets, single resolution layout code is preserved
- multiple sets of images, multiple/adoptable design resolutions, many device resolutions = less need to scale, code must be explicitly agnostic of the resolution (presumably more complex)

It is possible I've got something wrong since I've started looking into Cocos2dx not so long ago, but that's the results I've got after some testing.

Answer (score 1):

One returns points, logical pixels, the other physical pixels. In Retina displays both values are different (2x).

Comment: OK, currently I'm on an HDPI (retina MBP) display and I get the same value with both when running in debug mode from Cocos Code IDE. That's why I wasn't sure about their use. This must be a problem with the way the IDE packages the application then.